# Selenium IDE will select a drop-down option but Drupal won't recognize it

Tags: selenium, drupal, selenium-ide

I'm trying to automate a scenario in Drupal that includes changing the state of a page from Draft to Published via a drop-down menu.

Command is **click**
Target is **css=option**
Value is **published**

I can get Selenium IDE to perform the command (the test "passes"), but Drupal doesn't recognize that this happens, and instead shows me the draft page instead of a published page.

I've drop so many different commands and targets and nothing seems to work. What am I missing about this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the 'click' command doesn't pay attention to the value. All that command will do is click on the dropdown with that locator, which would expand it but not change the value.

Try using the 'select' command instead, and also adding in 'label=' in front of your value, so in this case your selenium command would look like:

`<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>css=option</td>
    <td>label=published</td>
</tr>`

Comment: Thanks very much. This worked, in combination with my realization that I was trying to break one command into two. Instead of click the menu then click the option, all I had to command was select the menu with the specific label.